# Some questions about Websphere session management stratagy and session related content in Servlet 2.3 specification

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, websphere

In documentation [Websphere Application Server Information Center - Clustered session support](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cprs_plan_cluster.html), it says

> The session management facility **requires an affinity mechanism** so that all requests for a particular session are directed to the same
>   application server instance in the cluster. This requirement conforms
>   to the **Servlet 2.3 specification** in that multiple requests for a
>   session cannot coexist in multiple application servers.

Does it mean Websphere can only support sticky session(session affinity) mechanism? If not, how to config on Websphere to support non-sticky session stratage?

And In  [Servlet 2.3 specification, SRV.7.7.2 Distributed Environments](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7840-servlet-2.3-spec-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_3-fcs-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1388998140_9a869ba45675b87e7c5a64bf4e340947)

> Within an application marked as
>   distributable, all requests that are part of a session must handled by
>   one virtual machine at a time.

Based on this specification, it supposes that we should follow this rule, but we can use non-sticky session stratage on **Apache + Tomcat cluster**, doesn't it break the rule?

Any response is appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to use WebSphere but not have existing sessions go to the same cluster member? (If so, why?) Or are you concerned about session failover when the primary cluster member isn't available?

Comment: @dbreaux, actually my applications on Webshphere are working with sticky session mechanism, the request from the same session will visit the same server. What I want to know is how to make the cluster work with non-sticky session, and if with non-sticky session mechanism, why it isn't breaking the Servlet specification rule?

Comment: Why do you want to make the cluster work with non-sticky session? And what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your second question: If you use Tomcat behind an Apache server, you're using a component (The Apache server) that is not JEE compliant, thus it doesn't have to follow any JEE rules.

Concerning your first question, with Websphere you can choose between using the proxy server, the HTTP plugin, and implementing your own proxy solution:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0m3/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_config_reverse_proxy_ihs.html&scope=null

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1010_pape/1010_pape.html

You can ignore session affinity by means of the CloneiD property on the plugin-cfg.xml file

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rwsv_plugincfg.html

> CloneID (zero or one attribute for each Server) If this unique ID is
>   present in the HTTP cookie header of a request (or the URL if using
>   URL rewriting), the plug-in routes the request to this particular
>   server, provided all other routing rules are met. If a CloneID is not
>   specified in the Server, then session affinity is not enabled for this
>   server.

Comment: Yes, it sounds reasonable.